# how to add li between each li using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this HTML CODE

```
<ul id='container'>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
<li>e</li>
<li>f</li>
</ul>
```

i want to add

```
<li class='separator'></li>
```

between each li's, at the beginning and at last. so my example will look like this:

```
<ul id='container'>
<li class='separator'></li>
<li>a</li>
<li class='separator'></li>
<li>b</li>
<li class='separator'></li>
<li>c</li>
<li class='separator'></li>
<li>d</li>
<li class='separator'></li>
<li>e</li>
<li class='separator'></li>
<li>f</li>
<li class='separator'></li>
</ul>
```

what is the best way to do that using jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Like this:](http://jsbin.com/uniyu3/edit)

```
var separatorHtml = '<li class="separator"></li>'

$('ul#container').children('li').after(separatorHtml)
$('ul#container').prepend(separatorHtml);
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited to satisfy the commentators ;)

```
$('li').each(function(){
$(this).after('<li></li>');
}).filter(':first').before('<li></li>');
```

I still think using each is useful as it makes further changes easier, but You can do it like that:

```
$('li').after('<li></li>').filter(':first').before('<li></li>');
```

PS. Pure CSS solution still would be better here. You can do separators with good border or background definitions (with some background position tweaking and paddings)

Comment: Almost correct, except he specifically wants a "separator" inserted after the last `li` as well.

Comment: Also, you don't need to call `after` in `each`.  http://api.jquery.com/after/ : ` Insert content, specified by the parameter, after _each_ element in the set of matched elements.`

Comment: Thanx guys. I didn't look too much, so I expected the separators only between stuff ;)